# Hibernate cant test my session, it's null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi im using eclipse this hibernate update.

i have this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>

  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

i have this class that has the basics to start hibernate:

```
package com.simpleprogramer;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static{
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch(HibernateException exeption)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory!");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and main that test hibernate session, and i don't know were is the null:

```
package com.simpleprogramer;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola mundo");
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

getting this error from console:

```
Hola mundo
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
oct 01, 2013 2:12:31 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Problem creating session factory!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.simpleprogramer.program.main(program.java:9)
```

---

Hi there, thank you for your advice exeption.printStacktrace(System.out);. I figure out that my jdbc driver was not loaded, and then realized that it wasn't loaded at all on the proyect (i thought that the config autoload no matter what or were the driver is). So i downloaded the corresponding jar and it works. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: It seems your `sessionFactory` has not been initialized. That's why the `NPE` when you try to `openSession()` on it.

Comment: @R.J yes, and OP's asking why

Comment: As a recommendation: you **should always** handle the exceptions. So in the `catch(HibernateException exeption)` you should at least add this code: `exeption.printStacktrace(System.out);` to log the error message and see the real error that produces this behavior.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I doubt if the OP knew what was causing the `NPE`, as the OP has mentioned in his question, *and i don't know were is the null*.

Comment: @R.J oh ok, agree. Then, let's wait for OP to update his/her code and edit the question to post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your advice exeption.printStacktrace(System.out);. I figure out that my jdbc driver was not loaded, and then realized that it wasn't loaded at all on the proyect (i thought that the config autoload no matter what or were the driver is). So i downloaded the corresponding jar and it works. Thanks for your advice!